# Probability that AJ is guilty

Tags: probability

A crime has been committed by a solitary individual, who left some DNA at the
scene of the crime. Forensic scientists who studied the recovered DNA noted that only five strands could be identified and that each innocent person, independently,
would have a probability of $10^{-5}$ of having his or her DNA match on all five strands.
The district attorney supposes that the perpetrator of the crime could be any of the
$1000,000$ residents of the town. $10,000$ of these residents have been released
from prison within the past $10$ years; consequently, a sample of their DNA is on file.
Before any checking of the DNA file, the district attorney feels that each of the ten
thousand ex-criminals has probability $\alpha$ of being guilty of the new crime, while each
of the remaining $990,000$ residents has probability $\beta$, where $\alpha$ = $c\beta$. (That is, the
district attorney supposes that each recently released convict is $c$ times as likely to
be the crime’s perpetrator as is each town member who is not a recently released
convict.) When the DNA that is analyzed is compared against the database of the
$10,000$ ex-convicts, it turns out that A. J. Jones is the only one whose DNA
matches the profile. Assuming that the district attorney’s estimate of the relationship
between α and β is accurate, what is the probability that A. J. is guilty?

---

The above is a question from [First Course in Probability](http://zalsiary.kau.edu.sa/Files/0009120/Files/119387_A_First_Course_in_Probability_8th_Edition.pdf) by
Sheldon Ross.The solved question is at page 93(of the pdf) in the linked pdf.

Now, the solution calculates  $P$(all in database innocent) as $=$ $1 -10,000\alpha$ .

*My Understanding* :
$P$(all in database innocent) = $1-$ $P$(at least one guilty in the database), but since only one can be guilty, all events ($i^{th}$ ex-criminal being guilty) are mutually exclusive, hence $P$(at least one guilty)= $\alpha+\alpha+..+\alpha$= $10000\alpha$.

*Doubt* : Why is  $P$(all in database innocent)  $\ne$ $(1 -\alpha)^{10,000}$? or Is $(1 -\alpha)^{10,000}$ $=$ $1 -10,000\alpha$?.

Comment: I'm innocent I tell you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning in the "My understanding" paragraph is right.

Why *would* it be $(1-\alpha)^{10000}?$ You *multiply* probabilities for *independent* events, but the events "ex-convict A is guilty" and "ex-convict B is guilty" are *not* independent. On the contrary, you have correctly identified them as being *mutually exclusive*, which is about as far from independent as you can come.

Comment: Well, it's embarrassing to say the least. For anyone else, this may help : http://math.stackexchange.com/a/941158/93949

Comment: In the above answer there is a comment - "If two events are mutually exclusive, then they are NOT independent" . Do you agree ? - I think the statement fails when any one of the events has zero probability.

Comment: @AtulGangwar: There is one loophole: If one of the events has probability $0$, then they can be both mutually exclusive and independent. However two events _with positive probability_ cannot be at once mutually exclusive and independent.

Comment: I think it is a criminal act to include a link to an illegal copy of a textbook.  The editors of this forum better remove the link to the illegal copy of the Ross book