# Find the probability of getting head and tail when fair coins are tossed

Tags: probability

You all might see it is very simple question , but i studied about independent events and then even there is a answer here :

[What is the difference between independent and mutually exclusive events?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941150/what-is-the-difference-between-independent-and-mutually-exclusive-events/941158)

A : event of occuring head in first coin

B : event of occuring tail in second coin

Clearly these are independent events so by the rule of probability

P(A and B) = P(A) * P(B) 
so then the answer is (1 / 2) * (1/ 2) 
which is 1 / 4 but when we see the sample space and answer this question it is coming 1 / 2 as they are 2 combinations of H and T in the sample space when tossing 2 coins

edit : Yeah i am sorry, i did not make my question clear. So when i am using the independent events concept to solve the question the ans is (1 / 4). But then when i am using sample space to answer this question ans is (1 /2). So which is the correct method of solving this quesiton and also please clarify me about why when using independent events is not working

Comment: There are $4$ equally probable outcomes of the two tosses:  $HH, HT, TH, TT$.  Each of these has probability $\frac 14$, for the reason you provide.

Comment: You made some statements but asked no question.

Comment: Hi, i have updated the question