# The relationship between independent and disjoint event

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How do we say that disjoint events are not independent? Isn’t the two concepts really different from each other?

According to what I have been taught, disjoint event deals with a *single trial* and independent event deals with *more than one trial*

To be specific on my point of doubt

Let’s say **A be the event of getting a head in a coin toss** and **B be the event of getting a tail**

In a single trial :
P(A|B)=0

But also isn't P(A and B) [in a single trial] = 0 in this case ?

Like when you toss a coin **once** you can’t get a head **and** tail right?

So why do we compare these two concepts when they are really talking about two different things?

I am sorry if I am missing something really obvious.

Thank you

Comment: they can be independent if the probability of one of them is zero

Comment: speaking informally, saying two events are independent means that knowing something about one (like if it happened or not) tells you nothing about the other.  Your coin toss is independent of your blood type, for example.  Knowing that you threw Heads, say, tells you everythibng you need to know about whether you threw Tails so those events are not independent.

Comment: There is a lovely explanation over on this old thread: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/941158

Answer (score 1):

These are two completely different concepts. If $A$ is the event where you get a head from a coin toss and $B$ is the event where you get a tail, then we have $\mathbb P(A\cap B)=0$, meaning that the events are disjoint. However since they are disjoint events, they must be dependent as if we know that $A$ has occurred, then $B$ must not have occured. In other words, $$\mathbb P(A|B)=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B)}{\mathbb P(B)}=\frac{0}{1/2}=0\ne \frac{1}{2}=\mathbb P(A)$$
(If events $A$ and $B$ are independent, we have $\mathbb P(A|B)=\mathbb P(A)$)