# Mutually Exclusive relationship with Independence

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, statistical-inference

Given Events A and B
If independent events means that the probability of event A occurring does not affect the probability of B occurring and mutually exclusive events means that A and B does not intersect - they cannot occur at the same time.
I understand that mutually exclusive events mean that they are dependent.

Given that we know 2 events are independent, what does that tell us about them being disjoint or not disjoint?

Independence intuitively tells me that they are not disjoint.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Doubts on Mutually exclusive and Independent events](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13367/doubts-on-mutually-exclusive-and-independent-events)

Answer (score 1):

If two events are independent, occurence of one does not have any affect on the probability of occurrence of the other. So, if $A$ and $B$ are independent $P(A)=P(A|B)$. Moreover, independent events can occur simultaneously; $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B)$ if A and B are independent. However, if two events are mutually exclusive, they cannot occur simultaneously so $P(A\cap B)=0$ if $A$ and $B$ are mutually exclusive. Consider the following example: flip a fair coin twice. Let F be the event that the first flip is a head, and S be the event that the second flip is a tail. Then, $P(F)=P({H,H})+P({H,T})=1/2$ and $P(S)=P({H,T})+P({T,T})=1/2$. Then, $P(F\cap S)=P({H,T})=1/4=P(F)P(S)$. Thus, $F$ and $S$ are independent and they have a nonempty intersection.